# What is the graph of $\sin^{\sin x}x$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as $$f(x)=\sin^{\sin x}x$$

I want an idea on the behaviour of this function.

Can anyone post the graph for the function $f$ on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Google is a good friend. You can google "online graphing calculator".

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(sin+x)%5E(sin+x) here you go

Comment: I tried but it gives me sin[(x)^sin x] that not what I want

Comment: @user479583 You can use brackets to specify what you're trying to write. `(sin x)^(sin x)` is best to describe this function to a graphing calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha will do the graphing: [link to the outcome](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20y%3D(sin%20x)%5E(sin%20x)).

Notice, that when $\sin x$ is negative, the value won't be real (except for when $\sin x = -1$). Wolfram Alpha shows the real part and imaginary part of the function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want only the graph of this function, [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) may help you.

This is the graph for $\sin^{\sin x} x$.

[image]

Also, you can have a look at the [graph](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin%20x%29%5E%28sin%20x%29) plotted by WolframAlpha.